# read the value from nested foreach loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have two String Array, i have to enter the value from the second array while the first array element is used to find webelement.
Here is the sample code:

```
public void isAllTheFieldsDisplayed(String values, String fields) {
    String[] questions = fields.split(",");
    String[] answers = values.split(",");
    for(String q : questions) {
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM - I want only the first answer from the String[] answers. similarly for the second question, i want the second element from the String[] answers.
   // THIS WONT WORK  - for(string ans : answers)
        find(By.cssSelector("input[id='"+q+"']")).sendKeys(ans);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to check whether the two arrays contain the same number of elements.

Utilising a simple integer for loop and slice the elements from the arrays:-

```
for(int i=0; i<questions.length; i++ {
  driver.findElement(By.id(questions[i])).sendKeys(answers[i]);
}
```

I assume the find method is some sort of wrapper for selenium's *findElement*
As id is being located suggest using By.id?

**Ideally check whether a WebElement is found before calling sendKeys**

Comment: Thanks!!! Mark Addison.It is working. This is very basic thing in java,I haven't tried, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach.  Which could be overkill depending on your environment.

Because of the coupled relationship of your questions and answers, we want to make sure they get paired correctly, and once they're paired there's no reason to distribute them separately anymore.

This could be a re-usable utility function like so:

```
public Map<String, String> csvsToMap(String keyCsv, String valueCsv) {
    String[] questions = keyCsv.split(",");
    String[] answers = valueCsv.split(",");

    // This could also be something like "questions.length >= answers.length" so if there 
    // are more questions than answers the extras would be ignored rather than fail....
    if (questions.length != answers.length) { // fail fast and explicit
        throw new RuntimeException("Not the same number of questions and answers");
    }
    
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        map.put(questions[i], answers[i]);
    }
    
    return map;
}
```

After the data has been sanitized and prepared for ingesting, handling it becomes a bit easier:

```
Map<String, String> preparedQuestions = csvsToMap(values, fields);

for (String aQuestion : preparedQuestions.keySet()) {
    String selector = "input[id='" + aQuestion + "']";
    String answer = preparedQuestions.get(aQuestion);

    driver.findElement(By.id(selector)).sendKeys(answer);
}
```

Or if java8, streams could be used:

```
csvsToMap(values, fields).entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(pair -> {
                String selector = "input[id='" + pair.getKey() + "']";
                driver.findElement(By.id(selector)).sendKeys(pair.getValue());
            });
```

Preparing your data in a function like this ahead of time lets you avoid using indexes altogether elsewhere.  If this is a pattern you repeat, a helper function like this becomes a single point of failure, which lets you test it, gain confidence in it, and trust that there aren't other near-identical snippets elsewhere that might have subtle differences or bugs.

Note how this helper function doesn't have any side effects, as long as the same inputs are provided, the same output should always result.  This makes it easier to test than it would be having webdriver operations baked into this task, as webdriver has built in side-effects which can fail at any time with no fault to your code. (aka talking to the browser)

Answer (score -1):

Iterator may resolve this, But i haven't  tried.

Iterator itr = questions.iterator();
Iterator itrans = answers.iterator();

while( itr.hasNext() && itrans.hasNext())